# How to open multiple files by its extension in subdirectories using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

all.

I got a code that works in a batch file, but it doesn't work as I expected. I want to open multiple files by its extension contained in the directory (and subdirectories) where the batch file is.

```
for /r "%~dp0" %%a in (*.mkv) DO "path\program.exe" "%%a"
```

That code open the first file perfectly, but it waits until I close the first file to open the second file. I need to open them all at once, to have like 20 windows popping up at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: You need the `start` command - see `start /?` for details

Comment: `start for /r "%~dp0" %%a in (*.mkv) DO "path\program.exe" "%%a"`? That doesn't even open the first one. :/ I've tried start "" for, same.

Comment: Keep in mind that `start ""` would come after `DO` in this example.

Comment: `for /R "%~dp0" %%I in (*.mkv) do start "Open %%~nI" "path\program.exe" "%%I"` although this command line does not really make sense as opening 20 video files with a program at the same time makes never sense.

Comment: It does for my need, @Mofi. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) said

```
for /R "%~dp0" %%I in (*.mkv) do start "Open %%~nI" "path\program.exe" "%%I"
```